# Call servlet from gwt client to download file

Tags: java, servlets, gwt, download, uibinder

I am trying to call a `servlet` from `GWT-client` to download a `file` generated at server.
Here is my `servlet` class

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String filename = someFile.xlsx;
    File file = new File("/path/to/files", filename);
    response.setContentType("application/x-download");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);


    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try {
        input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
        if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
    }
}
```

here is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>DownloadExcelServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.prmotions.server.DownloadExcelFileServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DownloadExcelServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/promotions/server/downloadExcel</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and on client side I am calling something like this

```
@UiHandler("exportExcel")
    void doExportHandler(ClickEvent event)
    {
        Window.open("/promotions/server/downloadExcel", "_parent", "location=no");
    }
```

The `servlet` is not being called, only popup opens up on button click. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's a type in your `web.xml`. "/prmotions/..." should be "/promotions/..."

Comment: sorry- typo, edited my post

Comment: Does the servlet gets invoked when you enter the URL manually?

Comment: No, It doesn't. It shows HTTP - 404 Error page

Comment: So you need to check why that is so - maybe you have an error in your configuration (typo in `web.xml`?), maybe there's an error when instantiating the servlet, etc.